# Counting occurrence of an item in a binary search tree

Tags: search, count, tree, binary, binary-search-tree

I am working on a count method for a binary search tree, but am not sure how to implement it.

```py
class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self, root: Optional[Any]) -> None:
        if root is None:
            self._root = None
            self._left = None
            self._right = None
        else:
            self._root = root
            self._left = BinarySearchTree(None)
            self._right = BinarySearchTree(None)

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        return self._root is None

    def __contains__(self, item: Any) -> bool:
        if self.is_empty():
            return False
        elif item == self._root:
            return True
        elif item < self._root:
            return item in self._left 
        else:
            return item in self._right

    def count(self, item: Any) -> int: # not sure how to finish implementing this
       if self.is_empty():
            return 0
        count = 0
        elif item == self._root: # python says this is an illegal target for variable annotation 
            count += 1
```

So far this method will return 0 if the tree is empty. It should raise the count by one if the root of
the tree is the item I am looking for.

But it won't let me compare the item with the root. Also, I
need to check the rest of the branches (left, right) to see if there are any more occurrences of the
item. Can I get some help as to how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two syntax errors in your code:

1. The indentation is not correct: the `if` is not indented as much as the corresponding `elif`
2. You cannot have another statement *between* an `if` block and an `elif` block, so `count = 0` cannot occur where you have it now, unless you change the `elif` into a plain `if`

Also, your function is designed to return an `int`, but only when the tree is empty, will it return that. In the other case it will return `None`.

You would need to apply recursion to make the count. If a BST has duplicate values then it could be that if you have arrived at the first occurrence, that there are duplicates both in its left and right subtree. So in that case you need to recur in both subtrees.

Here is how it could be coded:

```py
def count(self, item: Any) -> int:
    if self.is_empty():
        return 0
    count: int = 0
    if item == self._root:
        count = 1
    if item <= self._root:
        count += self._left.count(item) 
    if item >= self._root:
        count += self._right.count(item)
    return count
```